# Dynamically increase react-table height to fill screen size

Tags: reactjs, flexbox, react-table, react-table-v7

Is this possible to dynamically increase table height, based on the browser window height, when using the virtualized `react-table` ([example that I'm working with](https://codesandbox.io/s/github/tannerlinsley/react-table/tree/master/examples/virtualized-rows?file=/src/App.js)) ?

There's lots of empty space in my browser that I wish it'll fill up, yet I don't wish the table to overflow my screen, only to go up to the end of it (with a scrollbar allowing access to the remaining rows, if any).

[image]

I tried to use this flex box `css` code, but it didn't do anything. Note that I've successfully used this `css` code for a different component and it worked.

```
.flexbox-container {
  display:  flex;
  height:  100vh;
  flex-direction:  column;
}


.test1 {
  display: flex;
  flex-grow:  1;
}
```

I can see that the `react-table` example relies on `FixedSizeList` which seems to fix the height, which perhaps is disabling the flex box? I've tried to remove all the optional props but it didn't work.

```
<FixedSizeList
  height={800}
  itemCount={rows.length}
  itemSize={35}
  width={totalColumnsWidth+scrollBarSize}
>
  {RenderRow}
</FixedSizeList>
```

Comment: have you tried using npm package "react-virtualized-auto-sizer" ?
here is a working demo : https://codesandbox.io/s/3vnx878jk5

Answer (score 0):

When my application have multiple datas i solve with pagination
After user have a pagination hell (many-page)
i used react-window to solve problem after i confroted to your probleme
is solved to this code this sell hooks

```js
import React from 'react'
/**
 * Get small piece of screen to dynamic height table
 */
const calcHeight = (val) => (val - (Math.round(val / 4)))
export default function useHeight() {
    const [height, setHeight] = React.useState(calcHeight(window.innerHeight))
    const detectWindowHeight = (h) => setHeight(calcHeight(h))
    React.useEffect(() => {
        window.addEventListener("resize", (e) => detectWindowHeight(e.target.innerHeight))
        return () => window.removeEventListener("resize", (e) => detectWindowHeight(e.target.innerHeight))
    }, [])
    return { wH: height }
}
```

you can use variable wH => to dynamic height your table
Thanks to respond me !!!